# (Java RPG) object construction inside an if statement

Tags: java

I've made 4 classes (Mage,Rouge,Warrior&fool) that extend a class 'Character'. Each of these have their own specific battle methods inside their respective classes. However since only one of these objects are being constructed inside an if/else statement java doesn't recognize them as existing. The problem is I need to call the class specific method outside of the if/else statement. I tried initializing the 4 objects as null first then constructing/overwriting them but when I call the method it still refers to them as null. Formatting is a little screwed up but here:

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback!

```
public class Rpg {
    public static Warrior wplayer = null;
    public static Rouge rplayer = null;
    public static Mage mplayer = null;
    public static Fool fplayer = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        a2 = scan.nextInt();
        if (a2 == 1){
            Warrior wplayer = new Warrior();
        } else if (a2 == 2) {
            Rouge rplayer = new Rouge();
        } else if (a2 == 3) {
            Mage mplayer = new Mage();
        } else {
            Fool fplayer = new Fool();
            while (!notdone){
                System.out.println("1: Arena");
                System.out.println("2: Blacksmith");
                System.out.println("3: Shop");
                System.out.println("4: Leave town");
                System.out.println("5: Save and Quit");
                int choice = scan.nextInt();
                if (choice == 1 && wplayer != null){
                    wplayer.fightEnemy();
                } else if (choice == 1 && rplayer != null){
                    rplayer.fightEnemy();
                } else if (choice == 1 && mplayer != null){
                    mplayer.fightEnemy();
                } else {
                    fplayer.fightEnemy();
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: @nbokmans I might recommend you not to remove the `notdone==false` part and change it to `!notdone` without informing OP about it and why it should be done that way for readability and to prevent typos... However thanks for formatting the code...

Answer (score 3):

The scope of those variables is limited to inside the `if/else` blocks. If you want to access it outside, you should do the following:

```
Character player = null;

if (a2==1){
    player = new Warrior();
} else if (a2==2){
    player = new Rouge();
} else if (a2==3){
    player = new Mage();
} else{
    player = new Fool();
}

// by now, player was instantiated by some concrete class and you can use it
```

If each Character implements their own `fightEnemy()` method, then you can leverage polymorphism here to automatically choose the correct concrete method:

```
 ...
 if (choice==1){
        // java will figure out which "Character" this really is
        // then it will call the fightEnemy method for that specific "Character" type
        player.fightEnemy();
 }
 ...
```

Comment: You don't really need the `= null` part, since the compiler can see that the variable is guaranteed to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (a2==1){
    Warrior wplayer = new Warrior();
}
```

to

```
if (a2==1){
       wplayer = new Warrior();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in this code.

1. *Non-static* variable visibility is limited to `{}`. So you can see, that whe you write `if(a2 == 1) { Warrior wplayer = new Warrior(); }` then wplayer variable is visible only within `{}` and cannot be accessed after `if...else`. To fix it, you should define `Warrior wplayer` outside `if...else` and initialize inside `if...else`:

   Warrior wplayer = null;

   if(a2 == 1) {
       Warrior wplayer = new Warrior();
   }

   // wplayer is visible here
2. Additionnaly, you should look at structure of your code. You have several types of `Player`. All players have specific `fightEnemy()` implementation and to choose correct instance you use `if...else`. Imagine, if later you add some more type of `Player`, then you have to modify all these `if...else`. This is not good. Let me give you example how it could be done.

Example

```
interface Player {
    void fightEnemy();
}

class Warrior implements Player {
    public void fightEnemy() { }
}

class Rouge implements Player {
    public void fightEnemy() { }
}

class Mage implements Player {
    public void fightEnemy() { }
}

class Fool implements Player {
    public void fightEnemy() { }
}

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int a2 = scan.nextInt();

Player player;

if (a2 == 1) {
    player = new Warrior();
} else if (a2 == 2) {
    player = new Rouge();
{ else if (a2 == 3) {
    player = new Mage();
} else {
    player = new Fool();
}

System.out.println("1: Arena");
System.out.println("2: Blacksmith");
System.out.println("3: Shop");
System.out.println("4: Leave town");
System.out.println("5: Save and Quit");

int choice = scan.nextInt();

if (choice == 1) {
    player.fightEnemy();
}
```